# Fetch value in a specific row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

With this query :

```
select i.id, e.num_pieces, e.buff_id from item as i, equip_item as e
where i.id=e.item_id
and i.id=2
```

I have the following results :

```
id   num_pieces   buff_id
 2       2         3856
 2       5         4248
 2       7         6385
```

What I want to do is put these values into a div :

```
<div>
    <p>(2 parts) : buff<p>
    <p>(5 parts) : buff<p>
    <p>(7 parts) : buff<p>
</div>
```

However, I don't know how to fetch the values based on their column name and their row. Can anyone help me?

PS: It's not always 3 rows, sometimes there is more, sometimes there is less.

PS2 : I don't know if it's relevant but here is how I fetch the results :

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$row = $result->fetch();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = $result->fetchall();
```

Then lookup a foreach loop using keys